# Is there an issue with OpenJDK and the svg text attribute font-weight?

Tags: java, svg

A recent change from Oracle Java to OpenJDK has resulted a a difference in how our SVGs are rendered.  The text that has a font-weight attribute of "bold" is much more bold and there doesn't appear to be anything but not bold or really bold.  Here is an example of an svg text object

```
<text stroke="none" fill="black"  font-family="Franklin Gothic Book" font-size="9" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" x="145.490462303162" y="5.98640537261963" ><tspan baseline-shift="baseline">Underweight</tspan></text>
```

Is there a bug in OpenJDK?  I haven't been able to find a reference to one.

Comment: Are you sure your installed fonts haven't changed? Remember that setting font-weight is supposed to select a different variant, which is actually another font file.

Comment: The only thing changed was Oracle Java to OpenJDK

Comment: Oracle JDK used a proprietary font rendering engine. That engine needed to be replaced for the OpenJDK release, and so they switched to using Freetype.  The differences you are seeing could well be related to that change.  However it is also still possible that you have found a bug.  If you think you have, then you should report it to them.